# Instance variables: belonging to class Object vs belonging to instances

Tags: ruby

I was looking at [some Ruby documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Instance_Variables), and I found the following:

```
class MyClass
  @one = 1

  def do_something
    @one = 2
  end

  def output
    puts @one
  end
end

instance = MyClass.new
instance.output
instance.do_something
instance.output
```

Surprisingly, this outputs:

```
nil
2
```

The explanation in the documentation was following:

> This happens (nil in the first output line) because **@one** defined below **class MyClass** is an instance variable belonging to the class object (note this is not the same as a class variable and could not be referred to as **@@one**), whereas **@one** defined inside the **do_something** method is an instance variable belonging to instances of MyClass. They are two distinct variables and the first is accessible only in a class method.

I did not understand this explanation... So far all I got is that there are:

1. Class variables, similar to static attributes in other languages. This is clear.
2. Instance variables *belonging to the class object*
3. Instance variables *belonging to the instances*

I dont get point **2** & **3**

Point **2** sounds like point **1**, except that is says *explicitly* it is not. Point **3** sounds like the normal *class attribute*, except that it can't be defined outside a class method (??)

Can someone help me make sense of this, and maybe add some example so I can see the use of the existence of these 3 types of variables?

Answer (score 3):

Instance variables belong to instances (aka objects). Each object has its own instance variables.

There are two objects in the code above: `instance` and `MyClass`. Each of those objects has its own set of instance variables.

`MyClass` has an instance variable called `@one`, which is initialized to `1`.

The first time `output` is called, `instance` doesn't have an instance variable called `@one`, but that's okay: un-initialized and undefined instance variables don't raise exceptions, they simply evaluate to `nil`. When `do_something` is called, `instance`'s instance variable `@one` is created automatically (instance variables magically spring into existence the first time they are assigned) and initialized to `2`, so that the second time `output` is called, it now prints `2`.

`MyClass`'s instance variable `@one` is a red herring, it is never accessed in the code above (after line 2 where it is created and initialized, of course).

*Class Variables* are denoted with a double-at `@@` sigil. They belong to a class (actually, a module) and are shared between all subclasses, all instances, all instances of all subclasses, all sub-subclasses, all instances of all sub-subclasses and so on. They should be rather thought of as a (slightly) restricted form of global variables.

Answer (score 2):

Given the assignment:

```
class MyClass
  @@class_variable = 3
  @class_instance_variable = 1
  def initialize
    @instance_variable = 2
  end
end
```

the visibility is like this:

```
class MyClass
  def my_instance_method
    @@class_variable         # => Can refer (`3`)
    @class_instance_variable # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
    @instance_variable       # => Can refer (`2`)
  end
  def self.my_singleton_method
    @@class_variable         # => Can refer (`3`)
    @class_instance_variable # => Can refer (`1`)
    @instance_variable       # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
  end
  @@class_variable           # => Can refer (`3`)
  @class_instance_variable   # => Can refer (`1`)
  @instance_variable         # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
end

class SubClass < MyClass
  def my_instance_method
    @@class_variable         # => Can refer (`3`)
    @class_instance_variable # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
    @instance_variable       # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
  end
  def self.my_singleton_method
    @@class_variable         # => Can refer (`3`)
    @class_instance_variable # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
    @instance_variable       # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
  end
  @@class_variable           # => Can refer (`3`)
  @class_instance_variable   # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
  @instance_variable         # => Cannot refer (`nil`)
end
```